# Why does my holiday cactus have a three cornered stem segment?

Tags: diagnosis, growth, holiday-cactus

I noticed some new growth on my [*Schlumbergera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlumbergera), and when I looked at it, I found a three cornered stem segment. The segments are normally flat. with only two wings out from the stem. This segment has three.

Is that a disease, a sign of nutrient deficiency, or a genetic defect?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developmental abnormality, when the stem was very small some chemical signal got slightly messed up, sometimes maples get three seeds, I had a watermelon with three cotyledons this year... A four leaf clover would be the same sort of thing.

The stem is genetically the same as the stem it was connected to, stems growing from this one will likely be flat.